# If $A$ contains $B$ does $A$ have cardinality no less than $B$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $A$ contains $B$ does $A$ have cardinality no less than $B$? (Consider infinite case)

I looked up the wikipedia but there isn't much discussion into this. The only definition was using surjection. That means we can define identity surjection so that this conclusion can be reached?

(**see**:[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Definition_2:*.7C.E2.80.89A.E2.80.89.7C*.E2.89.A4_.7C.E2.80.89B.E2.80.89.7C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Definition_2:_.7C.E2.80.89A.E2.80.89.7C_.E2.89.A4_.7C.E2.80.89B.E2.80.89.7C))

Comment: What does it mean that $|A|\not<|B|$?

Comment: Greater or equal to. I suppose they have the same meaning?

Comment: Only under the axiom of choice. In any case, $|A|\ge|B|$ is trivial by definition. Do you know the set-theoretic definition of $\ge$?

Comment: A surjection from $A$ to $B$ implies this is all I know. How is this related to axiom of choice?

Comment: The definition of $|A|\ge|B|$ is that there is an injection from $B$ to $A$. (Under the axiom of choice, if there is a surjection from $C$ to $D$, then there is an injection from $D$ to $C$. But, just as before, choice is needed. Anyway, this is irrelevant for the matter at hand.) Do you see why in your case there is an injection from $B$ to $A$?

Comment: I still don't see the need of choice? Could you please further explain? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Consider the setup of the problem in your question. You want to construct a surjection from A to B, that is, assign a value in $B$ to each value in $A$. For $x\in B$, $x$ itself will do (and this will already guarantee that the complete function, if it exists, will be a surjection). But you need also a function value for $x\in A\setminus B$. How do you decide on one?

Comment: It is not easy to see that choice is needed, the technique of forcing is used to prove this. But it should be intuitively easy to see why it appears: If $f:C\to D$ is onto, associated to each $d\in D$ there is a subset $C_d$ of $C$, namely, the collection of those $c\in C$ with $f(c)=d$. This set is nonempty for any $d$ (since $f$ is onto) and obviously if $d_1\ne d_2$ then $C_{d_1}\cap C_{d_2}=\emptyset$. Now, if you want to exhibit an injection $g:D\to C$, it would be natural for each $d\in D$ to pick a point $p_d$ of this set $C_d$ and set $g(d)=p_d$. But "picking" involves choice.

Comment: To see that choice is needed to go from $|A|\not<|B|$ (meaning, there is no injection from $A$ into $B$) to $|A|\ge|B|$ (meaning, there is an injection from $B$ into $A$) the point is that this says that any two sets are comparable in size. This is one of the standard equivalent formulations of the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try identity function, which yields an INjection from $A$ to $B$

Comment: The identity function definitely does *not* yield a surjection from $A$ to $B$. Indeed, for $x\in A\setminus B$, the identity function on $A$ will produce a result that's not in $B$ (namely $x$).

Answer (score 0):

What *@monotonic* should have said:

Try identity function, which yields an INjection from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: I thank you for having answered questions with the _same account_ (instead of the following users PMar : http://math.stackexchange.com/users/349761/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/347147/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/325605/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/344183, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/357091, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/358074, https://math.stackexchange.com/users/369583, https://math.stackexchange.com/users/370376/). But it remains the account https://math.stackexchange.com/users/371886/pmar that you created $2$ days ago!

Comment: Another related account : 369844.